# How to close a window from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, xaml

For the life of me I can't find a solution for this.
I have a class set up that does several things, one of which is to do certain things to windows. One of them being the MainWindow.xaml

I want it to close the MainWindow.xaml if a method is called from within OtherClass.cs.
**Basically: I want to access methods in the codebehind of a window that is already instanced.**

---

Within Mainwindow.xaml.cs, which I tried to call from OtherClass:

```
public void CloseNow()
{
    This.Close();
}
```

But to access any members within MainWindow.xaml.cs I need it to be shared, but that would defeat the purpose of having it do anything to the window (MainWindow.xaml).

I might be overlooking some things, but atm I can't seem to notice it.
Would anyone be so kind as to show me a way to handle such a situation?

PS I am working in WPF.

---

To clarify, here is a comment to one of the answers:

> What I am trying to do is run a command within another class, which is a public member of a WPF window. The window is already instanced and displayed. I just want to access its public members so I can manipulate the window from another class for convenience sake. This OtherClass.cs of mine is a class that handles console actions. The console is a custom control situated in the MainWindow.xaml.cs. When the user types for instance: /close, I want the MainWindow.xaml to close, but not just that, for in the future I want to add more features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your OtherClass, add the below method to close the main window.

```
public void CloseMainWindowNow()
{
  var mainWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow);
  if (mainWindow != null)
  {
    mainWindow.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am working in Windows Presentation Foundation and an Application object is non existent for the window. Would you know an alternative?

Comment: The Application class exists in wpf, you need using System.Windows to access it.
But I think `Application.Current.RootVisual` is only available in Silverlight, you can use `Application.Current.MainWindow` in WPF.
And if closing you MainWindow exit the application, you can also directly use `Application.Current.Shutdown()`.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates can help you. Code in Windows Forms:

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = new Form2(Closing);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void Closing()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public delegate void Close();
    Close close;
    public Form2(Close close)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.close = close;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        close();
    }
}
```

So, when you press button1 on form2, it will use method close(), thaw was delegated from form1, so it will use method Closing on form1 and close form1.

Comment: Using a delegate is very inconvenient for me, because the second class (OtherClass.cs) is not a form. I have to write many methods that OtherClass.cs needs to access. Would you perhaps know an alternative?

Comment: In OtherClass constructor transmit reference to mainwindow.xaml.cs, and then you can call any methods of mainwindow, such as Close() or other, in OtherClass. Code I posted in other answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
class OtherClass
{
    private MainClass mainClass;
    public OtherClass(MainClass mainClass)
    {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
    }
}
```

And then you can call any methods of mainClass in OtherClass. In your case, MainClass is your MainWindow.Xaml.cs

In MainWindow.Xaml.cs you have to create Otherclass otherClass = new OtherClass(this);